# How to have all elements inherit one particular property from base class?

Tags: css, less, stylesheet

Using LESS, I need to set the color of many decedent elements based on the class set in their body tag.

e.g

```
<body class="color-a">
  <h2 class="news-heading">Hi Buddy</h2>
  <p class="news-body">How are you doing?</p>
</body>
```

I have many colors, color-a, color-b, color-c, color-d, etc, all the way up to 20 different variations.

Using nested selectors, the color is being written 20 times per class.

e.g.

```
.color-a .news-heading { color:blue; }
.color-b .news-heading { color:red; }
.color-c .news-heading { color:green; }
```

What is the best way to write this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General Answer

As stated in another answer, `color` inherits automatically ([as this example shows](http://jsfiddle.net/bXKmp/)), but that is assuming nothing else is setting `color` of the `h2` elements (your `.news-heading`). If css sets the `color` of that element elsewhere, [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bXKmp/1/), then you would need to override. Yes, you can override it as you are, making 20 different class calls to explicitly override ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/bXKmp/2/)) it per color, but it would be better to do that override in one single call like the following code, which then does not matter what the `color` is on `body`, as it will take that `color` as its own. Of course, [it will only do so if your selector is high enough in specificity to win the selection battle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

```
.news-heading {color: inherit;}
```

Now while `color` (your particular case) usually inherits automatically, many properties do not, yet can still be set to `inherit` as a value. [See the listing of what values are allowed and whether inheritance is the default or not.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) At present, I believe all properties can be explicitly set to `inherit`.

So the more general answer to your question is, for whatever "one particular property" you want to inherit from is, you can set it just like the above. So you could do something like this (theoretically):

```
.myClass {
  background: inherit;
  border-style: inherit;
  border-color: inherit;
  border-width: inherit;
  float: inherit;
}
```

[See example fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bXKmp/8/) Note that `background: inherit` is different than simply letting the `background` of the parent be seen through a transparent child (transparency is default; which some people may think is inheritance, but is not). In [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/bXKmp/8/), you should be able to see a slight shift in `background` for the children that are inheriting it verses those that are not. This is because the background is actually repainting itself from (in this case) the top left corner of the child elements over the top of the parent background.

Note that inheritance is from the *immediate* parent. One cannot inherit from a grand-parent element without first setting the parent to inherit as well. [See this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bXKmp/10/).

Answer (score 2):

Colors already inherit by default, so if you want *all* descendants of `body` to have the same font color, it's sufficient to specify the color on the `body` class, once per class name:

```
.color-a { color: blue; }
.color-b { color: red; }
.color-c { color: green; }
```

If there are any elements you happen to want to exclude, you can specify that in a single separate rule. For example, if you want `.news-body` to simply remain black and not inherit the color:

```
.news-body { color: black; }
```

You can only prevent inheritance from a parent element, not to child elements, so while this will prevent the `body` color from being passed down to `.news-body`, any descendants of `.news-body` will still inherit, but will do so from this rule instead.

This does not require any special LESS code. [Inheritance](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#inheritance) is a feature of vanilla CSS.

Comment: But if `.news-body` is a different color for each of the color classes, then they can't use just plain inheritance from the parent.  I thought that was the issue the OP had.

Comment: you can add class .color-a to .news-body.

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to solve this problem

1.You can use specific class for every color:

```
.color-a { color: blue; }
.color-b { color: red; }
.color-c { color: green; }
```

and add these classes on the element that you want to stylize

2.Another way is to use Less for this:

```
.color-a(){
   color: blue;
}

.news-heading{
  .color-a();
}
```